# Python 3 Beautiful Soup 4 .findall not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and beautifulsoup, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I was trying to create a **webscraper** that takes the name of an inputted country and finds its money supply from the following website (https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/money-supply-m2). Whenever I try to find all the a tags it keeps giving me this error:

```
"AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. 
You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? "
```

Whenever I remove the .find_all(a) it works.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



url4='https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/money-supply-m2'
def run_scraper():
  print('running')
  country=input('Please input the name of the country: ')
  
  content4=requests.get(url4).text
  soup4=BeautifulSoup(content4,'html.parser')
  t=country.title()


  table=soup4.find('table',{'class':'table table-hover'})
  for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    co=tr.find_all('td').find_all('a')
    print(co)
      

run_scraper()
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Answer (score 3):

`find_all` returns (essentially) a list. A list does not have a `find_all` method.

You need to iterate over all `td` elements, just like you already iterate over all the `tr` elements:

```
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        co = td.find_all('a')
        print(co)
```

Comment: Oh alright that explains it. Thank you so much for your help.